# C++ merge 2d arrays (reffed by uniqe_ptr) into 3d array

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, unique-ptr

I need to merge three 2D arrays into a 3D one.

I'm using unique_ptr to reference the 2D arrays.

Im quite new to smart pointers and C++ in general, so chances are it's an obvious mistake.

```
int imgsize = 15;
std::unique_ptr<float[]> redptr(new float[imgsize]);
std::unique_ptr<float[]> greenptr(new float[imgsize]);
std::unique_ptr<float[]> blueptr (new float[imgsize]);

redptr = redChannel._data;
greenptr = greenChannel._data;
blueptr = blueChannel._data;

float * colourArr[3] = {redptr,greenptr,blueptr};
```

Comment: I see no multidimensional array whatsoever in this code snippet. (also, `std::vector`)

Comment: [What are you trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The idea behind a `std::unqiue_ptr` is that the `std::unique_ptr` has *sole* ownership of the pointed to object. Structuring the code as posted contradicts this premise, as another variable now has a pointer to the object owned by the `std::unique_ptr`.</strike> The posted code is dangerous as it is a potential source of dangling pointers (once the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope the pointed to object will be destructed but the elements of `colourArr` would still point to the, now destructed, objects).

Instead of using `std::unique_ptr` and explicitly dynamically allocating memory suggest using a [`std::vector<std::vector<float>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. This will manage the memory and provide array style access via [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at):

```
// Construct a vector contain 3 elements,
// where each element is a vector containing 'imgsize' floats.
std::vector<std::vector<float>> colourArr(3, std::vector<float>(imgsize));
```

Comment: Having a pointer to the object owned by the unique pointer is common and doing so safely is quite within the grasp of most programmers.